# Is there a MySQL feature like SQL Server 2005's TRY/CATCH blocks?

Tags: mysql

I'm thinking about porting a database from Sql Server 2005 to MySQL.

I've become accustomed to using SQL Server's TRY/CATCH block in stored procedures.

Does MySQL have something similar, or am I going to be forced to go back to the old-school "check the error return after every statement, and issue a goto if it failed" style of programming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare [handlers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html) for specific error results.

Answer (score 0):

There is no try/catch in MySQL as far as i know.
Here something that can help with the errors in stored procedures:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SELECT 'SQLException invoked';
```

Source:http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/