# MySql try catch

Tags: mysql

I want syntax for try catch  in MySql stroed procedure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352022/is-there-a-mysql-feature-like-sql-server-2005s-try-catch-blocks

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any. You can use [signal/resignal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html).