# MySQL try catch

Tags: mysql

```
If(variable1='table name1')
BEGIN TRY
...........
...........
.....
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
        RAISERROR ('FAILED TO GET DATA FROM hh_usr_card_dtls',16,-1)      
        RETURN -1
    END CATCH
```

The above code is in SQL (MS SQL),
I want implement same thing in MySQL. Can you please help me?

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396715/mysql-try-catch

Answer (score 0):

No, MySQL does not have that functionality.