# Logging with MYSQL Handlers

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, handlers

I'm hoping this isn't just duplicating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352022/is-there-a-mysql-feature-like-sql-server-2005s-try-catch-blocks).

I have read the documentation but I don't think I fully understand how to use this properly yet.

I would like to catch errors thrown in my stored procedures and log those errors in a table. This is mostly for experimental purposes. I am wondering is there a way to catch any error and then log the code and error to a table.

So far it looks like I have to declare a different handler for each error. Is this correct or is there a way to catch all errors and get the code and message.

For example in each stored procedure I'm declaring a couple of handlers

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Attempt to create a duplicate entry occurred';
END;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
ROLLBACK;
SELECT 'Unexpected Error Ocurred';
END;
```

Instead of

```
 SELECT 'custom message';
```

I want to do

```
INSERT INTO errorLogs(code, message);
```

Is this possible without declaring a load of handlers and adding each code manually?

Really appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not really possible until I can use an updated version of MYSQL with DIAGNOSTICS. I found [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5746/equivalent-functions-in-mysql-that-exist-in-sql-server) which is basically the same as mine. Ah well.